# Propel 1.7 parameter mapping to unix time

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I am trying to convert a large SQL query to Propel.

if I add

```
->where("ads_table.date>DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL ? DAY)", $interval)
```

to the query and set `$interval` to `30`, the generated SQL looks like this:

```
AND ads_table.date>DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL '1970-01-01 01:00:30' DAY)
```

How do I get it to see the parameter as an int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer in the Propel docs (I know).

```
->where("ads_table.date>DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL ? DAY)", $interval, \PDO::PARAM_INT)
```

does the trick.